# Yup validation array of strings that cannot be empty string

Tags: formik, yup

```
const values = { phoneNumbers: \[\] };

const validationSchema = Yup.array().min(1, 'Required').notOneOf(\[''\]);
```

I would like to validate the array that cannot be empty string value and at least one item include. What did I wrong?